# How to convert spark dataset to scala seq

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following case class

```
case class Station(id: Long, name: String) extends Node
```

and a Spark Dataset of stations

```
vertices: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Station] = [id: bigint, name: string]
```

I would like to convert the vertices Dataset to a Seq[Station].
I found a lot of tutorials about how to create a Dataset from a sequence but not vice versa. Do you have any hint for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collect--) to convert the Dataset to an `Array`. You're free to then  convert to `Seq`:

```
val verticesSeq: Seq[Station] = vertices.collect().toSeq
```

Use with caution though:

> Running collect requires moving all the data into the application's driver process, and doing so on a very large dataset can crash the driver process with OutOfMemoryError.